# Rails 4.2 How to convert a table to a matrix similar to a calendar:

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let’s say I have a table like this:

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwihQ.jpg)

I need to convert that table into a matrix that organize the items by their levels horizontally and the categories vertically.
The result will be like this:

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWTjA.jpg)

Is there any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

*I'll refer to image 1 as table 1 and image 2 as table 2.*

A row in table 2 consists of **level, category 1, category 2, ..., category X**. We can see you need a column for each category, so the first thing you want to do here is get the set of the categories from table 1.

```
require 'set'

# A set of all the categories extracted from table 1
categories = Set.new

table1 = [
  { title: 'Item 1', level: 1, category: 'Category 1' },
  { title: 'Item 2', level: 1, category: 'Category 2' },
  ...
]

# Extract categories from table 1
table1.each do |item|
  categories << item[:category] # add category to set
end
```

The next thing we can see here is that in table 2 items are arranged by their level and category. We need a way to say "give me the items (more than one possible) at level X with category Y". Thus table 2 can be represented like follows:

```
table2 = {
  level1: { category1: [...], category2: [...], category3: [...] },
  level2: { category1: [...], category2: [...], category3: [...] },
}
```

As an example, with this you would get the (level 1, category 2) items using

```
table2[:level1][:category2]
```

The next task is to convert from table 1 to table 2. This is simple given the above representation of table 2 and can be done by iterating through table 1 and just adding the item (or rather its title) into the appropriate level and category array of the `table2` hash.

```
# Arrange items by level and category
table1.each do |item|
  table2[item[:level]] ||= {} # hash of categories for this item's level
  table2[item[:level]][item[:category]] ||= [] # array of items for this item's level and category  
  table2[item[:level]][item[:category]] << item[:title] # add item to its corresponding array
end
```

...and you now have your data in the representation you want.

One thing to note in table 2 is that (level 1, category 1) has two items and uses two separate rows to represent this. If you want to output like that then you need to iterate through each level, and for each level iterate through each category, and **for each item** at (level, category) print a row. You can see an example of how to do that in the full source below (which you are free to use if you want):

```
require 'set'

table1 = [
  { title: 'Item 1', level: 1, category: 'Category 1' },
  { title: 'Item 2', level: 1, category: 'Category 2' },
  { title: 'Item 3', level: 2, category: 'Category 3' },
  { title: 'Item 5', level: 3, category: 'Category 3' },
  { title: 'Item 6', level: 1, category: 'Category 1' },
  { title: 'Item 7', level: 2, category: 'Category 2' },
  { title: 'Item 8', level: 4, category: 'Category 1' },
  { title: 'Item 9', level: 4, category: 'Category 3' }
]

table2 = {
  # 1: { category1: [...], category2: [...], category3: [...] },
  # 2: { category1: [...], category2: [...], category3: [...] },
}

# A set of all the categories extracted from table 1
categories = Set.new

# Extract categories and also arrange items by level and category
table1.each do |item|
  categories << item[:category] # add category to set

  table2[item[:level]] ||= {} # hash of categories for this item's level
  table2[item[:level]][item[:category]] ||= [] # array of items for this item's level and category
  table2[item[:level]][item[:category]] << item[:title] # add item to its corresponding array
end

# Print headers for table 1
puts
puts 'Title | Level | Category'

# Print rows for table 1
table1.each do |item|
  print item.values
  puts
end

# Print headers for table 2
puts
print 'Level | '
categories.each do |category|
  print category + ' | '
end
puts

# Print rows for table 2
table2.each do |level, categorised_items|
  row = 0

  loop do
    last_row = true

    # level for this row
    print level
    print ' | '

    # print item for each category
    categories.each do |category|
      if categorised_items[category] && categorised_items[category][row]
        print categorised_items[category][row] + ' | '

        # check if an item exists for the next row
        last_row = false if categorised_items[category][row + 1]
      else
        print ' | '
      end
    end

    puts

    break if last_row

    row += 1
  end
end
```

Output:

```
Title | Level | Category
["Item 1", 1, "Category 1"]
["Item 2", 1, "Category 2"]
["Item 3", 2, "Category 3"]
["Item 5", 3, "Category 3"]
["Item 6", 1, "Category 1"]
["Item 7", 2, "Category 2"]
["Item 8", 4, "Category 1"]
["Item 9", 4, "Category 3"]

Level | Category 1 | Category 2 | Category 3 | 
1 | Item 1 | Item 2 |  | 
1 | Item 6 |  |  | 
2 |  | Item 7 | Item 3 | 
3 |  |  | Item 5 | 
4 | Item 8 |  | Item 9 |
```

Comment: Thank you cthorne, I'll apply your solution and get back to you :)